# How to destroy specific backend session programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, session

- I am doing login and logout to magento backend via API.
- I am enable to create the session and pass to API response to my UI part.
  But when I log out from UI , the API should destroy that backend session
  How can I achieve this?

I am trying to do with below code.

```
$adminSession = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$adminSession->unsetAll();
$adminSession->getCookie()->delete($adminSession->getSessionName());
```

any one can help quickly will force my progress
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$adminSession = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
```

Comment: Thanks but not gettting success

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Unset session values, try this.. It will help you.

```
$adminSession = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
$adminSession->unsetData('day_filter'); // use session name instead of 'day_filter'
$adminSession->unsetData('days');
$adminSession->unsetData('next_delivery_date');
```

Comment: Thanks but not getting success

Comment: I set session file name : "sess_vqvn8a24445npbsrjtgd67qtm2" at place of 'days_filter' and execute the code but the file is not get deleted.